# How to validate input in child component

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am migrating an AngularJS 1.6 application to Angular 12. I am having a problem migrating a form to a Angular template-driven-form:

```
<form novalidate #myAwesomeForm="ngForm" name="myAwesomeForm">
    [...]
</form>
```

which contains input fields inside of child-components:

```
<my-child-component
    [model]="myModel"
    [fieldId]="'someText'">
</my-child-component>
```

In the AngularJS-form we could easily validate all those nested input fields via e.g.

```
formName.inputName.invalid
```

But this doesnt seem to be working anymore. I was able to add the inputs to the NgForm via

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-child-component',
    templateUrl: './my-child-component.component.html',
    viewProviders: [ { provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm } ]
})
```

in the child component, but this only gives me the possibility to check if the whole form is valid. I can also get all the input values of the form via

```
myForm.value
```

which returns an object with all field-names and their values, but I can't check a specific input field to show a more specific error message or styling this input, like

```
<div [ngClass]="myAwesomeForm.childComponentInputField.invalid ? 'has-error' : ''">
    <my-child-component
        [model]="myModel"
        [fieldId]="'someText'">
    </my-child-component>
</div>
```

Is there some way I can achieve that in Angular?

Comment: Can you give me your form structure ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use reactive-forms here. Build your form via the form-builder's (injected via the constructor) group-method. There you can also set Validators to your form-controls (inputs).

See: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#validating-form-input

Answer (score 0):

In a template-driven Angular form you can always get a reference to any control-enabled component and then just check its validity the same way you would do with a form or with a component in AngularJS:

```html
<form #myAwesomeForm="ngForm">
    <my-child-component-1 [model]="myModel1" #control1></my-child-component-1>
    <my-child-component-2 [model]="myModel2"></my-child-component-2>

    <div>Form is <span *ngIf="myAwesomeForm.invalid">not</span> valid</div>
    <div>Control 1 is <span *ngIf="control1.invalid">not</span> valid</div>
</form>
```

Comment: What does "control-enabled" mean exactly? The child-component contains more than just the input, there are also divs around it.

Comment: UPDATE - Well I guess I messed a bit regarding concepts. If you want your components to be "understandable" by a form, they must first implement interface [`ControlValueAccessor`](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) in order to be considered a form control -- then standard validations (empty, length, etc) can already be performed by a form and determine if it is valid or invalid.

Comment: Ooooh, I see, thanks! So basically I can add this form-functionality to custom components, like in my case?

Comment: Please see my updated comment -- but basically yes, you can make your component be "understandable" and "validatable" by a form. And if you find this answer helps you, please accept it as valid answer.

Comment: I sure will, but I still don't know how to implement this. All you posted is the html...

Comment: I managed to make it work with ControValueAccessor. Only problem here is: It seems you can't prefill the input of the custom component... The values on the controller are correct and prefilled, but not the input in the view.

Comment: To prefill the input of a custom control-enabled component use `writeValue` method provided by the `ControlValueAccessor` interface.

Comment: Regarding code... you don't need more code in order to get the `invalid` values. I am already showing you how to access it in the `<span>`s

Comment: I was talking about the code regarding the usage of the ControlValueAccessor, I've never heard of it before... An example of the components code and usage of these methods would have been nice.  I guess I need to use writeValue in onInit? Still, thanks for the hint.

Comment: `writeValue` is one of the methods you have to implement in order to implement interface `ControlValueAccessor`. Is what forms will use to initially fill a value to your component. If I didn't put that in the answer is because that was not asked. I actually answered to your question in my answer. For more info on implementing `ControlValueAccessor` you can see https://medium.com/@majdasab/implementing-control-value-accessor-in-angular-1b89f2f84ebf or further info on Google.